# How do I search for an actual asterisk in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I want to search for and replace "*", an actual `Shift + 8` asterisk.
There is no option to turn wildcards on and off like there is in Word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the tilde (~) just before the asterisk to tell Excel that it is a literal.

Ref:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214138

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you do if you need to search for a tilde? Would you use "~~"?

Comment: Yes.  Note, this is the second example in the MS support link.

Comment: It sure is. I got a little lazy there. Thanks.